# Cannot run method on child fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

I have a fragment that hosts `FragmentTabHost`. On every tab change event, I want to run a method from the child fragment. But the method always throws null pointer exception.
Here is my fragment that contains `FragmentTabHost`:

```
public class OverviewFragment extends Fragment {

    private Context mContext;

    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    private EventFragment mEventFragment;
    private AttendanceFragment mAttendanceFragment;
    private InboxFragment mMessageFragment;

    public OverviewFragment() {
        mContext = getContext();
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
     */
    public static OverviewFragment newInstance() {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        OverviewFragment fragment = new OverviewFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public static OverviewFragment newInstance(Bundle args) {

        OverviewFragment fragment = new OverviewFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview, container, false);

        mContext = getContext();

        mEventFragment = EventFragment.newInstance();
        mAttendanceFragment = AttendanceFragment.newInstance();
        mMessageFragment = InboxFragment.newInstance();

        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(mContext, getChildFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Events"),
                mEventFragment.getClass(), null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Messages"),
                mMessageFragment.getClass(), null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Attendance"),
                mAttendanceFragment.getClass(), null);

        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                Bundle args = getArguments();

                switch (tabId) {
                    case "tab1":
                        try {
                            mEventFragment.updateView();
                        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                            Log.e("EventFragment", "Fragment not loaded");
                        }
                        break;
                    case "tab2":
                        try {
                            mMessageFragment.updateView();
                        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                            Log.e("MessageFragment", "Fragment not loaded");
                        }
                        break;
                    case "tab3":
                        try {
                            mAttendanceFragment.updateView();
                        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                            Log.e("AttendanceFragment", "Fragment not loaded");
                        }
                }
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

This is my child fragment:

```
public class InboxFragment extends Fragment {

    private Context mContext;
    private StaticListView mMessageListView;
    private DatabaseHandler mDatabaseHandler;
    private MessageListAdapter mMessageListAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Message> mMessageList;
    private TextView mFragmentTitle;
    public boolean isLoaded = false;

    public InboxFragment() {
    }

    public static InboxFragment newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        InboxFragment fragment = new InboxFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public static InboxFragment newInstance(Bundle args) {
        InboxFragment fragment = new InboxFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);

        mContext = getContext();

        updateView();
        return rootView;
    }

    public void updateView() {
        Bundle args = getArguments();

        LocalDate selectedDate;

        if (args != null) {
            int selectedYear = args.getInt(Application.KEY_YEAR),
                    selectedMonth = args.getInt(Application.KEY_MONTH),
                    selectedDay = args.getInt(Application.KEY_DAY);

            selectedDate = new LocalDate(
                    selectedYear,
                    selectedMonth,
                    selectedDay
            );
        } else {
            selectedDate = LocalDate.now();
        }
    }
}
```

Calling `mInboxFragment.updateView()` always returns `NullPointerException`. It is same for all other classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **interface**. Or this method should be static method. Otherwise it will always return null.

Comment: Can you tell me why it returns null? And also how to implement interface in my case

Comment: @AayushSubedi `mEventFragment = EventFragment.newInstance();`, you are creating new instance of mEventFragment, it means you are allocating new memory to it. Therefore when you call the method it returns null pointer exception.

Comment: For implementing interface: Your InboxFragment will implements the interface and you will call your method in interface method. Now you can call the updateView() method by using your interface.

Comment: I am calling the method from the tab change listener. So at that point shouldn't ta Fragment be already initialized??

Comment: And also please provide an example for above case for implementing interface